# Best way of setting default_url_options[:host] in a class inside a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a helper called MailersHelper inside app/helpers:

```
module MailersHelper

  class MailerBody

    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    def initialize data
      set_instance_vars data
    end

    def text(*args)
      @inst_url = "Institution url: #{provider_url(@provider)}"
      ...
    end

  end

end
```

I initialize `MailerBody` from a mailer called `AdminMailer`:

```
def notify_course_modified course
  body = MailerBody.new(course).for_c_modified
  mail(...,body: body)
end
```

However, I got the following error:

> Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set     default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

(the trace points to line where `provider_url(@provider)` it's called)

**development.rb**:

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => "localhost:3000"}`

However, inside BodyMailer, `default_url_options[:host]` is nil.

I could pass it when initializing the BodyMailer, but that just feels wrong. Any easy solution or something obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

I settled:

```
  config.after_initialize do
     Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
  end
```

in config/environments/development.rb, inside the block

```
Rails.application.configure do
```

I needed to add it for test and production too.

Answer (score 0):

It results that is `ActionMailer::Base` who defines `default_url_options[:host]`. I just had to set it up on initialization:

```
def initialize data
  default_url_options[:host] = ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]
  set_instance_vars data
end
```

That made it.